# Callback inside of method in an ES6 class calling another method

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, closures, electron

I'm trying to do the following.

```
  listening(randomToken, self) {
    console.log("test");
  }

  startListening(randomToken) {
    let test = caller => {
      this.listening(randomToken, this);
    };

    this.udpSocket.on("listening", test);
  }
```

I call startListening from another class but the output of console.log("test"); is never displayed in the Chrome console.

However, when I do:

```
  startListening(randomToken) {
    let test = caller => {
      this.listening(randomToken, this);
    };

    this.udpSocket.on("listening", this.listening(randomToken));
  }
```

The output is displayed correctly, *but* I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function

Why is this happening? Of course I can avoid the error from displaying by wrapping it around a try/catch, but is there a more proper way of dealing with this?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that even this doesn't work:

```
    let test = caller => {
      console.log("test");
    };

    this.udpSocket.on("listening", test);
  }
```

Comment: So it looks like `updSocket.on` is never calling the callback? Where does it come from? Are you sure there's a `listening` event fired by it?

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply

I instantiated a class called ClientController, and then from within a React component (that I'm using in an electron app), I fire the clientController.startListening() method on an onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass 'test' as a function,

`this.udpSocket.on("listening", test());`

Comment: whenever I do this, I get the same error as for the second snippet I posted, that is:

Uncaught TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function